# Spring Keycloak adapter Permissions Policy Enforcer. How to set it up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, privileges, keycloak

First of all I'm using

- keycloak-authz-client-3.3.0.Final
- spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-security

I've been playing with Keycloak spring adapter exploring the examples since we want to adopt it to our project.

I was able to make it run for Roles easily using this tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-k

After that I moved to permissions and that's when it gets trickier (that's also our main goal).

I want to achieve something like described in here (9.1.2):
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.4/authorization_services_guide/topics/enforcer/authorization-context.html#

- To get permissions you need to setup in Keycloak Authorization, credentials, and then create Resources or Scopes and Policies to be able to create permissions (it took me a while but I got it working). Testing in the Evaluater everything seems fine.
- Next step was to get user permissions on the Spring side. In order to do that I had to enable:
  keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=permissive

The moment I enable this I get everytime this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find resource.
at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.findAll(ProtectedResource.java:88)
at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.configureAllPathsForResourceServer...
...
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: 
Unexpected response from server: 403 / Forbidden
```

No matter what address I hit in the server.

- So I started to investigate what was the root of the problem. Looking at some examples how to manually get the permissions I actually got them in postman with the following request:
  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${myKeycloakRealm}/authz/entitlement/${MyKeycloakClient}
  including the header Authorization : bearer ${accessToken}
  response was {"rpt": ${jwt token}} that actually contains the permissions
- So knowing this was working it must be something wrong with the Spring adapter. Investigating a bit further on the Keycloak exception I found that that error was occurring the moment the adapter was getting all the resources. For that it was using the following url:
  http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/license/authz/protection/resource_set
  with a different token in the headers (that I copied when debugging)
  So when I tried it in postman I also got a 403 error, but with a json body:

{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "Requires uma_protection scope."
}

I've enabled and disabled all uma configuration within keycloak and I can't make it work. Can please someone point me into the right direction?

**Update**

I've now updated Keycloak adapter to 3.4.0.final and I'm getting the following error in the UI:

Mon Nov 20 10:09:21 GMT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not find resource. Server message: {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Requires uma_protection scope."}

(Pretty much the same I was getting in the postman request)

I've also printed all the user roles to make sure the uma_protection role is there, and it is.

Another thing I did was to disable spring security role prefix to make sure it wasn't a mismatch on the role.

**Update 2**

Was able to resolve the 403 issue (you can see it in the response below).
Still getting problems obtaining KeycloakSecurityContext from the HttpServletRequest

**Update 3**

Was able to get KeycloakSecurityContext like this:

```
    Principal principal = servletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal;
    OidcKeycloakAccount auth = token.getAccount();
    KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = auth.getKeycloakSecurityContext();

    AuthorizationContext authzContext = keycloakSecurityContext.getAuthorizationContext();
```

The problem now is that the **AuthorizationContext** is always null.

Comment: Hi @Luis Perdigao, I am also trying to get spring boot with permissions but in my case i am also not getting the permissions in the  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${myKeycloakRealm}/authz/entitlement/${MyKeycloakClient}  call. I created a resource and a js based policy and added the permission. The policy looks for an attribute in the user and if that is true its granted. In the rpt token i don't see the attribute or the permission, do you know how we can make this work

Comment: if the permission is set to that user you should be able to see it there. Go to keycloak authorization tab -> evaluate and test the permissions that you are suppose to have in there. If that doesn't help, try to add more generic permissions and see if they appear in the request

Comment: i was able to run one of the quickstart REST Spring boot applications using ABAC. I was wondering whether you were able to make it work with policy-enforcer or without it. My question basically is is it always necessary to have policy-enforcer because if we have that it always invokes the Keycloak server to validate which we would like to avoid for every call if possible

Comment: No. You only need the policy enforcer if you want roles or privileges dealt by the application aka authorization. Keycloak invocation is not on every call. If I remember right it will avoid another call as long as you set the access token validity.

Comment: thanks. It does not invoke the keycloak server on every request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to get it working by adding uma_protection role to the **Service Account Roles tab in Keycloak client configuration**

[image: Here's the place where it is in Keycloak]

More information about it here:
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.0/authorization_services_guide/topics/service/protection/whatis-obtain-pat.html

Second part of the solution:

It's mandatory to have the security constrains in place even if they don't mean much to you. Example:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = ROLE1
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = protected
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /*
```

Useful demos:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts

Comment: Thanks, had this problem with exporting a keycloak 11.0.3 Realm and importing it in a 11.0.3 Realm bc. the client was not exported / imported correctly

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```js
HttpServletRequest request = ...; // obtain javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
KeycloakPrincipal < KeycloakSecurityContext > keycloakPrincipal =
  (KeycloakPrincipal < KeycloakSecurityContext > ) userPrincipal;
KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext =
  keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
```

Comment: AuthorizationContext of securityContext is null. keycloak:15.0.2

Comment: @withoutOne have you managed to solve this issue ?

Comment: @Samir I dont remember but I guess I writed to application.properties any empty securityConstraints and it was worked. Example is inside the answer that was checked by man who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you faced "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find resource" error and you are using Keycloak docker container, The error can be because of this. I dont have enough information about docker. Hence I download keycloak as a zip file and run it. It works properly.